# Comparing percent change of model coefficients

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am working through step 3 of purposeful model-building from Hosmer-Lemeshow and it suggests to compare the percent change in coefficients between a full model [Iris.mod1] and a reduced model [Iris.mod2]. I would like to automate this step if possible.

Right now I have the following code:

```
#Make species a binomial DV
iris = subset(iris, iris$Species != 'virginica')
iris$Species = as.numeric(ifelse(iris$Species == 'setosa', 1, 0))

#Build models
Iris.mod1 = glm(Species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, 
data = iris, family = binomial())

Iris.mod2 = glm(Species~Sepal.Length+Petal.Length, data = iris, family = 
binomial())
```

The dataset I am actually using has about 93 variables and 1.7 million rows. But I am using the iris data just for this example.

```
#Try to see if any coefficients changed by > 20%
paste(names(which((summary(Iris.mod1)$coefficients[2: 
(nrow(summary(Iris.mod1)$coefficients)),1] - 
(summary(Iris.mod2)$coefficients[2: 
(nrow(summary(Iris.mod2)$coefficients)),1]/
(summary(Iris.mod1)$coefficients[2:nrow(summary(Iris.mod1)$coefficients)),1] 
> 0.2 == TRUE)))))
```

However, this code is full of errors and I am lost in a sea of parenthesis.

Is there an efficient way to determine which variables coefficient changed by more than 20%?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nice to see the improvements - I would add a caveat to my advice about accepting answers. It's important to do, but don't do it *too fast*. Often people recommend waiting 12-24 hours just to see if any other better answers come along. (With exceptions, if the answer really seems perfect go ahead and accept immediately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `broom` package is really nice for making data frames of model coefficients and terms. We can use that to get things in a workable format:

```
library(broom)
m_list = list(m1 = Iris.mod1, m2 = Iris.mod2)
t_list = lapply(m_list, tidy)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(t_list, .id = "mod") %>%
    select(term, estimate, mod) %>%
    spread(key = mod, value = estimate) %>%
    mutate(p_change = (m2 - m1) / m1 * 100,
           p_change_gt_20 = p_change > 20)
#           term         m1        m2 p_change p_change_gt_20
# 1  (Intercept)  -6.556265 -65.84266 904.2709           TRUE
# 2 Petal.Length -19.053588 -49.04616 157.4117           TRUE
# 3  Petal.Width -25.032928        NA       NA             NA
# 4 Sepal.Length   9.878866  37.56141 280.2199           TRUE
# 5  Sepal.Width   7.417640        NA       NA             NA
```